# Combine two line graphs into one line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is the first part of the line graph that i want:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = monthly_data, aes(x = Date.Recorded, y = Sale.Amount), color = "blue") +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Sale Amount') +
  ggtitle('Sale Amount Trend and Forecast') +
  xlim(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2025-12-31"))
```

[image]
this is the second part of the line graph that i want:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_path(data = forecast_data_clean, aes(x = Date.Recorded, y = Sale.Amount), color = "red") +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Sale Amount') +
  ggtitle('Sale Amount Trend and Forecast') +
  xlim(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2025-12-31"))
```

[image]
but i cant combine them together into one line graph via the code as follows:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = monthly_data, aes(x = Date.Recorded, y = Sale.Amount), color = "blue") +
  geom_path(data = forecast_data_clean, aes(x = Date.Recorded, y = Sale.Amount), color = "red") +
  xlab('Date') +
  ylab('Sale Amount') +
  ggtitle('Sale Amount Trend and Forecast') +
  xlim(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2025-12-31"))
```

it will show:[image]
how to solve the problem for me to combine first and second part together in one line graph.

Comment: What do you mean specifically by “but i cant combine them together”? At first glance, without having example data to test on, I would guess this would work. Do you get an error (if so, what error)? Do you get a result that is different from your expectation (if so, how)?

Comment: ya, i updated the plots that i got from the first and second part data, but when combined them together i didnt show the trend from 2019-2025, just show a horizontal line for 2022-2025.

Comment: Is it possible your forecast is in different units, eg 1,000s or millions?

Comment: what do you mean in different units? is it refer to the y-axis the sale amount?

Comment: @regina What Jon is saying is that the scale of your forecast is orders of magnitude smaller than the Sale Amount. The Sale Amount has a max of 8000000000 and so the axis goes from 0 to 8e09. The forecast is no more than 3000000, and so it will look like a horizontal line on a y axis of 0 to 8e09. One would expect that the units to be similar between the forecast and the Sales Amount, but they are very different. It suggests that there is an error. If there is no error in your model, then consider using a log10 scale for your y axis.